# How to group days(7days) into weeks using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to group every 7 days into a week but my issue is that the the hours for the first week is always off by a lot.  What i mean by this is that we work 40 hours a week but ALWAYS the hours for first week is way off and the remaining weeks are okay.  For example:

```
WeekBeginDate   TotalHours
7/6/2015           10
7/13/2015          40
7/20/2015          40
```

I know the first week should be 40 but it shows less than 40 hours.  Here is my sql.

```
Select  x.UID, 
        Convert(VarChar, x.WeekBeginDate, 101)  As WeekBeginDate, 
        x.TOTAL_HOURS 
From
(
    Select  UID,  
            DateAdd(DD, Convert(Int, (DateDiff(DD, '1/1/1900', t.DT) / 7)) * 7, '1/1/1900') [WeekBeginDate],                              
            Sum(HOURS)  As TOTAL_HOURS 
    From    myTable     t 
    Where   UID = 'mike01' 
    And     DT >= DateAdd(Week, -3, GetDate()) 
    Group By UID, Convert(Int, DateDiff(DD, '1/1/1900', t.DT) / 7)
)x;
```

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the datepart function?

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE())
```

** EDIT **

I see what you're trying to do. Just convert all dates to beginning of the week and group by it.

```
SELECT UID,
       DD - DATEPART(dw,DD) + 1 AS [WeekBeginDate], 
       SUM(HOURS) AS [HOURS]
FROM dbo.mytable
WHERE UID = 'mike01'
GROUP BY UID, DD - DATEPART(dw,DD) + 1
```

Here is the setup script I used to test it.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    [UID] varchar(100),
    DD DATETIME,
    [HOURS] DECIMAL(18,2)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable
        ( UID, DD, HOURS )
VALUES  ('mike01', '2015-07-30',1),
    ('mike01', '2015-07-29',6),
    ('mike01', '2015-07-23',2),
    ('mike01', '2015-07-16',3)
```

Comment: no, i want to get the total hours for the last 3 weeks and group them by week